# Using CORS and Fetch API to return Authenticated Cookie from another domain

Tags: javascript, wordpress, cookies, cors, fetch

I am trying to get the background on a login button that is on the navigation of my WordPress site I work on to change based on if someone is logged into their account on another website that doesn't share a domain. I reached out to the guys who work on the other site and they have set CORS up on there end and I have set it up on my WordPress site too. I am using the Fetch API to retrieve the Authenticated Cookie that is generated when someone is logged in and the cookie appears in the cookie list on my WordPress website through the Chrome devtools but when I try to return the value within my JavaScript code, the cookie appear to not be detected. The code I am using is below.

```
// Replace with the URL of the other website you want to access cookies from
const otherWebsiteUrl = 'www.othersite.com';

// Replace with the name of the cookie you want to access
const cookieName = 'Authenticated';

async function getCookieValue() {
  // Wrap the code that contains the `await` keyword in an async function
  const response = await (async () => {
    const response = await fetch(otherWebsiteUrl, {
      method: 'GET',
      mode: 'cors',
      credentials: 'include',
    });

    if (response.ok) {
      const responseText = await response.text();
      const parsedCookies = responseText.split(';');

      for (const cookie of parsedCookies) {
        const [name, value] = cookie.split('=');
        if (name.trim() === cookieName) {
          return value;
        }
      }
    }

    return null;
  })();

  return response;
}

// Wrap the code that uses the `cookieValue` variable in an async function
async function setLoginButtonBackgroundColor() {
  const cookieValue = await getCookieValue();

  if (cookieValue) {
    document.querySelector('#loginBTN').computedStyleMap.backgroundColor = '#d9d9d9';
  }
}

setLoginButtonBackgroundColor();

const cookieValue = document.cookie.split(';').find(cookie => cookie.includes('Authenticated'));

if (cookieValue) {
  // The cookie exists
  console.log("Authenticated Cookie Exists");
} else {
  // The cookie does not exist
  console.log("Authenticated Cookie Doesn't Exist");
}
```

I have tried asking the other engineers on the other team but they don't seem to know how to get it to work.

I have tried just getting the value of the cookie back but it doesn't appear in the console. Only place I can see the Authenticated cookie is within the list of cookies under the application tab within the dev tools, so that should mean that the CORS and Fetch API is working right? It has to be my code.

Answer (score 1):

Client-side JavaScript has access (through [document.cookie](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/api/document/cookie)) to **same-origin** cookies. It has **no access** to cross-origin cookies.

Using `credentials: 'include'` will allow an Ajax request to send cross-origin cookies and for a cross-origin response's `Set-Cookie` header to set cookies for that origin.

This is handled *transparently*. There is no way for client-side JS to access the value of those cookies. It can only make requests to which they are automatically attached.

You are using `await response.text()`. This will return the response body as a string. Cookies are set using the [`Set-Cookie` header](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Set-Cookie), not the body.

To read headers, you can generally use [the `headers` object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response/headers) but `Set-Cookie` is [a forbidden response header](https://fetch.spec.whatwg.org/#forbidden-response-header-name) so it will not work for that particular one.

It is possible for the URL you are making the request to to return a copy of the cookie data in the request body, but you've given not indication that it does.

Comment: Thanks for the information, not sure I am closer to understanding what it going on but I will read up on the links you provided. Just want to ask though, even though I am not planning to change the Authenticated cookie, just want to see if it is there, would I still need to use set-cookie in order for the cookie within the code to have a value?